# Word for selling something that you don't use anymore

Tags: word-request

Is there a single word (or a short expression) for selling something (usually online, like on craigslist etc., also possibly garage sales) that you don't use anymore?

Comment: Depending on whether you're interested in any money you might get from the process, you could either say you're ***monetising*** or ***recycling*** your unwanted possessions. If all you care about is freeing up some space in your garage / attic, you might say you're ***having a clear-out.*** Personally, I often refer to ***Freecycling*** my old tat (one man's garbage is another man's treasure trove).

Comment: A good word is **divest**, but it doesn't apply only to items that are no longer used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided sufficient context to give you much of an answer beyond generic phrases like selling **used** or **pre-owned** or **second-hand** items.

You could be **getting rid of junk** you don't want.  You could be selling items that some people would consider rare finds. You could be selling items that still have lots of life and use left that shouldn't go to waste.

Comment: "Getting rid of..."  Sometimes you trash it.  Sometimes you sell it.  Sometimes you tell it to leave and not come back.

Comment: @EllieK: https://lifehacker.com/you-must-get-started-on-your-swedish-death-cleaning-1819370181

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any one specific word for selling a single item.  Something close to what you are thinking of might be the phrase 'declutter.'  If a family was going to hold a garage sale to get rid of things they really don't need anymore they might say they are going to 'declutter' the house.  As in "get rid of the unneeded clutter."

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my answer.

For the actual act of selling, and using as few words as possible:

"**Selling your cast-offs.**"

The noun [cast-off](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cast-off) (as opposed to the adjective **obsolete**):

> Something, especially a garment, that is no longer wanted.
>
> ‘I'm not going out in her cast-offs!’

---

While the *act* of selling something can have different descriptions (and you would need to clarify the intent behind it), the thing itself could be considered [**obsolete**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolete):

> a : no longer in use or no longer useful · an *obsolete* word
>   b : of a kind or style no longer current : old-fashioned · an *obsolete* technology · farming methods that are now *obsolete*

This is not to say that if something is obsolete *for you* it is necessarily obsolete for somebody else. (Hence the saying "one person's junk is another person's treasure.")

Comment: When I clicked on this question I thought of the same word, but I don't think it's really used with *things you can hold in your hands* (unless they are a piece of technology). Would you describe an old shirt as obsolete?

Comment: @userr2684291 Yes. As in "no longer useful" or "it's outlived its usefulness," as per the first sense. That's what garage sales are for—to get rid of obsolete (and now unwanted) items.